# How to get the adjacent matching using Regular Expressions and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have wrote the following code:

```js
var RegExpression = new RegExp ("!?[a-z][&|]!?[a-z]", "g");
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert(document.getElementById ("expression")
  .value.match(RegExpression).join(", "));
 });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="expression">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit!">
```

I want to get from this code the following:

> Example input: !a&b|c&!d&e|f
>
> Output: !a&b, b|c, c&!d, d&e, e|f

, but I get:

> Output: !a&b, c&!d, e|f

How to fix it?

If anything, I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: can you explain what is your code trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it can be done directly with a regex or not, but one thing you can do is use the `.exec()` method of the regex object in a loop instead.

Because your regex is `g` global, the regex object maintains the state of the ending point of the last match. This is stored at the `.lastIndex` property of the regex object and is mutable, so you can simply decrement it one position before doing the next call.

```js
var re = /!?[a-z][&|]!?[a-z]/g;
var input = "!a&b|c&!d&e|f";
var match = null;
var result = [];

while ((match = re.exec(input))) {
  result.push(match); // Add the match to our result Array
  re.lastIndex -= 1; // Start the next call on the last char of the last match
}

console.log(result.join("\n\n"));
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```js
const input = document.createElement('input')
const result = document.createElement('div')
input.value = `!a&b|c&!d&e|f`

    const split = data => {
        const result = data.replace(/(!?\w+)/g, '$1,$1').replace(/.*?,/, '')
        return result.substr(0, result.lastIndexOf(',')).split(',')
    }

input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  result.innerText = split(input.value).join(', ')
})

document.body.appendChild(input)
document.body.appendChild(result)
```

Comment: Your result is close, but not quite the same. The second to last match has included the `!` at the start. But maybe the OP is OK with that.

Comment: I think that this makes sence

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(!?[a-z][&|]!?[a-z])).
```

A matching group inside a positive look ahead can be used to match overlapping groups. The dot in the end is just used to proceed.

The output would be:

!a&b, a&b, b|c, c&!d, !d&e, d&e, e|f

which is more than you wanted, but if you want solve this with plain regex this should be close.